# DBeaver. Не могу нормально подключиться с клиентской машины через Dbeaver к Postgres. Он пишет, что подключается, но ни таблиц, ни представлений нет

Tags: dbeaver

С клиентской машины под Windows через Dbeaver пытаюсь подключится к серверу с Postgres-ом. Подключаюсь через SSH туннель. Потом настройка подключения собственно к базе данных: Название сервера, порт 5432, имя нужной базы данных, Метод аутентификации: Database Native, имя пользователя, пароль. Dbeaver пишет, что подключение прошло успешно. Появляется база с нужным мне именем, но когда я вхожу в схему  public, в таблицы или представления, там всё пусто. При том, что если я захожу в эту же базу с сервера через psql там все мои 42 таблицы присутствуют.
Почему я не вижу их в Dbeaver-е?

Comment: Проблему удалось решить.

Answer (score 0):

Проблему удалось решить. Это была неочевидная особенность Dbeaver. Dbeaver пытается подключить не ту базу, которую указываешь, а одноимённую с пользователем, и если такой базы не обнаруживается, он ругается, говорит, что такой базы не существует и не подключается. А если зайти под пользователем postgres, то он подключиться к базе postgres, даже если указана другая база данных. Причём имя базы данных в навигаторе написано правильно, но открывая таблицы, понимаешь, что это про другую базу данных. А если в настройках во вкладке Postgresql поставить галочку отображать все базы данных, то он правильно отобразит имена всех баз данных, но если попытаться зайти в их таблицы, то они будут у всех одинаковые и принадлежать собственно базе данных одноимённой с пользователем. Косяк, однако.
Пришлось завести пользователя с таким же именем как и нужная база данных.

Comment: День добрый. А можно уточнить, пожалуйста Вашу версию DBeaver? Я вот сейчас подключилась с юзером1 к базе с названием2, указав название2 в настройках подключения как имя базы. И вижу соответствующие базе с названием 2 таблицы и схемы. Меня беспокоит Ваш комментарий, и хочется разобраться :)

Comment: Здравствуйте, Анастасия. Я меняю версии Debeaver регулярно, как только он просит. Сейчас у меня 22.2.5 , на тот момент не помню какая была версия (та которая была последняя на дату вопроса. Но проблема осталась и в версии 22.2.5 .

Comment: Только что попробовала добавить ещё одно соединение. И тоже самое.